# C# StreamReader in a try/finally

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question today involving the StreamReader class. Specifically initializing this class using the filename parameter for example:

```
TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileName);
```

Obviously when this action is finished, its important to close the stream like this:

```
 tr.Close();
```

I would like to have this in a try / finally, the problem is I can't find a way to do this. Here are some variations I have found that DO NOT work:

```
    try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileName);
            var obj = serializer.Deserialize(tr);
        }
    finally
        {
            tr.Close();    
        }
```

and worse:

```
     TextReader tr;  
        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
            tr = new StreamReader(fileName);
            var obj = serializer.Deserialize(tr);
        }
        finally
        {
            tr.Close();    
        }
```

So is it possible to have a StreamReader close in a finally?

Comment: Declaring TextReader tr; so it is available to the finally is not a problem.  But using is better answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `using` statement:

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
  // ...
}
```

The compiler will generate a try-finally block for you and put code to call Close (actually Dispose) in the finally.

If you need to spell out the `finally` explicitly, your second example will work, except that you need to force `tr` to be initialised:

```
TextReader tr = null;
```

And you will of course want to check for `tr != null` inside your finally block, in case an exception happened before `tr = new StreamReader(...)` was executed.

Comment: Dernit. Beat me to the post :)

Comment: So that means the close method, does not need to be manually called?

Comment: JL: correct.  `using` will ensure that the Dispose method is called for you, and for TextReader Close and Dispose are the same thing (the name Close is retained for historical reasons).  You can call Close manually inside the using block if you want to close the reader early for some reason, but the compiler will generate the Dispose call behind the scenes as part of its expansion of the `using` keyword.  So no, Close does *not* need to be manually called if you use `using`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, either:

```
TextReader tr = null;
try
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
    tr = new StreamReader(fileName);
    var obj = serializer.Deserialize(tr);
}
finally
{
    if (tr != null)
        tr.Close();    
}
```

or just:

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
    var obj = serializer.Deserialize(tr);
}
```

The reason the first piece of code in your question did not compile was that the `tr` variable was declared inside the try-block, which made it inaccessible to the finally-block.

The reason the second piece of code in your question did not compile was that the `tr` variable was not given a value, and if the `new XmlSerializer` were to throw an exception, it wouldn't get one in the try-block either, which means you have a possible undefined value in the variable when it reaches the finally-block.

The solution, if you want to absolutely keep a try/finally structure, is to ensure the variable has an initial value, and only call `.Close` if it has changed.

Of course, the most correct way is to use a `using` block, which takes care of all the details for you. Note that this will change the order of construction between the reader and the serializer object, or you can have the code like this, which preserves the order you had in your question (it won't matter in this case though):

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    var obj = serializer.Deserialize(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A comment about this code

```
TextReader tr;  
        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
            tr = new StreamReader(fileName);
            var obj = serializer.Deserialize(tr);
        }
        finally
        {
            //tr.Close(); 
            // Correct way
            if (tr != null) tr.Close();
        }
```

What happens if `StreamReader` fails, then the `finally` block gets executed, now, here, `tr` is still `null` as a result of the failure, you will end up with an exception inside the `finally` block!

It is preferable to catch the `System.IO.IOException` so that you will be handling the situation properly instead of masking the problem with the file input/output handling...

Answer (score 2):

Don't use try/finally here, use the Using statement, which does the same thing as what you're doing with cleaner syntax. The answer is "yes", btw :)

Answer (score 2):

you should use the `using` keyword.

```
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    var obj = serializer.Deserialize(tr);
}
```

the Dispose() method will be called with the object goes out of scope at the end of the block.